error: The getter 'home_page' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'. (undefined_getter at [project] lib/main.dart:106)
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.home_page('call_emergency_services');

I have set up the localizations system but this code shows the error above. I want to access call_emergency_services from @home_page. This format is included in the documentation (https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization).

You need to provide minimum reproducible code examples to get answers, your question is so ambiguous.
